# Is it possible to play a Youtube video using WebView in Android

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I've gone though many tutorials found on Google and none of the answers really work. I would like the video to play in the WebView instead of going though the YouTube app. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Code:

```
 public class Youtube extends Activity {
WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.website);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost()
                    .equals("http://www.youtube.com")) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView
                // load the page
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
            // another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
    // to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Must it be a WebView? Have you seen https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player ?

Comment: Yes but that would need 4.2+ I need ICS+. Also I want to load a channel not just a single video. Thanks for trying though. :)

Comment: That's 4.2 version of **YouTube**, not Android. From the page I linked: *Generally, devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo) or later that have the Google Play Store app installed will receive updates within a few days. As a result, your application can use the YouTube Android Player API and reach most devices in the Android ecosystem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new YouTube Android Player API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player

"*The API defines methods for loading and playing YouTube videos (and playlists) and for customizing and controlling the video playback experience.*"

So for using with a Channel, you'd use the regular YoutTube API to get the metadata, and play the videos/playlists with the Player API.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to do this, sorry only beginner.

Comment: I've never used it, but the docs are quite extensive. They even have a handful of sample apps that should be more-than enough to get you on your way: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try working around this code after defining the webView in your layout's xml file:

In the MainActivity, get the instances of WebView controls and convert the iFrame code of the embed YouTube video to a string. Then enable Javascript and load the video iFrame string to the webview instance by using the loaddata() of the WebView.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = null;
    private View mCustomView;
    private RelativeLayout mContentView;
    private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bDLIV96LD4");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
            mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
            mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
            view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return;
            } else {
                // Hide the custom view.
                mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Remove the custom view from its container.
                mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
                mCustomView = null;
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
                // Show the content view.
                mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setContentView(mContentView);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mCustomViewContainer != null)
            mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
        else if (myWebView.canGoBack())
            myWebView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

The entire tutorial is found here: http://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-play-youtube-video-inside-android-webview-using-video-url/